# Hadoop : single node vs cluster performance

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am running three MapReduce jobs in sequence (output of one is the input to another) on a Hadoop cluster with 3 nodes (1 master and 2 slaves).

Apparently, the total time taken by individual jobs to finish on a single node cluster is less than the above by quite a margin.
What could be the possible reasons? Is it the network latency? It's running on 100Mbps Ethernet network. Will it help if I increase the number of nodes?

I am using Hadoop Streaming and my code is in python2.7.

Comment: What is the volume of data you are processing?

Comment: 358,773,680 Bytes text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapReduce isn't really meant to handle that small of an input dataset.  The MapReduce framework has to determine which nodes will run tasks and then spin up a JVM to run each individual Map and Reduce task(s) (the number of tasks is dependent on the size of your data set).  That usually has a latency on the order of tens of seconds.  Shipping non local data between nodes is also expensive as it involves sending data over the wire.  For such a small dataset, the overhead of setting up a MapReduce job in a distributed cluster is likely higher than the runtime of the job itself.  On a single node you only see the overhead of starting up tasks on a local machine and don't have to do any data copying over the network, that's why the job finishes faster on a single machine.  If you had multi gigabyte files, you would see better performance on several machines.